# Find incidence angle from wave equation?

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

The equation is the following $$E_i=-E_0[e^{-j(5\sqrt 3y-5z)}\hat x+\frac{1}{2}e^{-j\pi/2}e^{-j(5\sqrt 3y-5z)}\hat y+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}e^{-j\pi/2}e^{-j(5\sqrt 3y-5z)}\hat z]$$
The following are also given : $ε=2ε_0$  for   $z>0$

$3ε_0$ for $z<0$

$μ$ is $μ_0$ for both areas

How can I find the angle ? I think I can find the wave number and wavelength and more using n1 and n2 but I have no idea how to find the angle . Usually I have an equation for just one unit vector . I don't know how to face this one . And where is time in this equation ?

One more thing that confuses me is that we have two variables , z and y . I usually look at the coefficient in front of z for the wave number . What am I doing here ?

Comment: I have corrected my diagram to reflect the fact that the was a $-j$ outside the bracket.  I am sorry that I did not see it when I posted my original answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And where is time in this equation ?

You are possibly looking at the values of the electric field vector at time $t=0$ and this is sometimes called a wave profile, a "photograph" of the wave at an instant in time.

Assuming that the interface is the $z=0$ plane then the diagram below.

[image]

> One more thing that confuses me is that we have two variables , z and y . I usually look at the coefficient in front of z for the wave number.

The wave is not travelling in a direction which is the same as one of the unit vector.

The $\vec k$ vector has two components which are shown in the diagram and you are asked to find the angle $\theta$ assuming that the required angle is relative to a normal to the $z=0$ plane..

Answer (score 2):

You left out some important details so I'll guess the interface is the $z=0$ plane.  With this your electric field phasor $\tilde E$ is of the form
$$
\tilde E=\vec E_0 e^{j\vec k\cdot r}=\vec E_0 e^{j(k_yy+k_zz)}
=\vec E_0e^{jk(y\sin\theta+z\cos\theta)} \tag{1}
$$
The rightmost expression follows because you want $\theta=0$ to be normal incidence, in which case $\vec k$ would be along $\hat z$ only.

By direct comparison of (1) with your form we find
$$
k_y=k\sin\theta=-5\sqrt{3}\, ,\qquad k_z=k\cos\theta=5
$$
from which you can extract $\tan\theta=k_y/k_z$.  This should be close enough for you to make he final adjustments.

Comment: The usual form is not to the power of minus j but just j. Do I need to take the minus inside and then take the wave numbers ?

Comment: @JohnKatsantas I've re-jiggled the answer to bring it to your standard form.